# In Fabric, How to scale an object in one direction while the perpendicular direction is fixed?

Tags: html, fabricjs

I know the object can be scaled in X axis with Y axis is fixed. But I need to scale an object in one direction which is neither horizontal or vertical, while the perpendicular direction is fixed, is it possible?

For example, if there is a line object which is not horizontal or vertical,  I want the length of a line can be extended, while the width cannot be changed.

Comment: the length of a rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting!
How about using `angle`?
I create a example in https://jsfiddle.net/sapics/mq00xq3y/105/.